# Parsing an XML String without parsers tools

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing

I have the following string (it doesn't come from a file : it comes from a db) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <person name="dave">
        <job>teacher</job>
        <job>musician</job>
    </person>
    <person name="chris">
        <job>farmer</job>
    </person>
</root>
```

Of course, the example is simplified.

I have to parse it "manually" with basic String functions (for example: I can't use XML Parsers).

I created a HashMap :

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList> personsAndJobs = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>
```

But, I can't find a good algorithm that can store the data like this :

```
for each "person" tag {
   // put the "name" attribute in a HashMap 
   personsAndJobs.put(person.get("name"),null) 
   jobs = new ArrayList<String>();
   for each "job" of that person{
       jobs.add(job.getTagContent())
   }
   personsAndJobs.put(person.get("name"),jobs) 
}
```

This is the alogrithm I'm trying to put in place.

Can anyone help me to translate that algorithm into Java ?

Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: Why are there requirements not to use an xml parser?  No need to re-invent the wheel, unless you're doing it just for education.

Comment: Also, you can just use the built-in to Java XML parser, thus if there are issues with "external" parsers, this averts it, as it uses the parser that comes bundled with the JVM.

Comment: I cannot understand why you can't use xml parser? is it a homework?

Comment: It already seems to *be* the algorithm! I certainly would only put the person & jobs in personAndJobs when I got both ready, but otherwise you seem to go in the right direction. Oh, at least use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList for the jobs, unless the jobs need to be ordered. That makes looking up if somebody got a particular job a lot faster (e.g., find all teachers).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a special tag class that stores tag name and all attributes as fields plus references to its children tags in arrays or array lists.
Then put all top level tags in their own array or array list. From here iterating through all
 persons and their subtags is a piece of cake.

Comment: ArrayLists are slow when looking up items, I would go for HashMap and HashSet any time. And you can iterate through them just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

This smells of homework, so you are going to get an over simplified, likely borked idea that you can build on or ignore at your leisure. Consider using a stack to keep track of where you are in the xml document.

```
push root tag
While(stack is not empty)
    read tag
    if close tag
        pop tag, continue
    if person
        push tag onto tag stack
        get name, create person, add to persons stack, continue
    if job
        push tag onto tag stack
        get job, add job to person on top of the stack.
        pop tag
```

Finding out which tag is which is generally not too hard, using string.contains (“tag”)  should be enough. This little bit of pseudo code isn’t particularly robust, multiline job tags will break it, but with a little programming magic, it’s easy enough to deal with. If you are being asked to create a solid, robust xmlparser in JAVA, you've got a long night ahead of you.